# JavaScript Hoisting: Function Can Refer to Another Function Declared Below It?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, hoisting, lexical

I have:

```
// Shouldn't we have the following hoisted?
// var multiply; (undefined)
// var add; (undefined)

var multiply = function(num) {
  return add(num) * 2;
};

var add = function(num) {
  return num + 1;
};

console.log(multiply(1)); // No error, somehow "multiply" calls "add"!
```

I thought that JavaScript variables are hoisted to the top, but not the values that they are assigned to. Somehow `multiply` calling `add` doesn't return an error, even though `add` is declared below `multiply`.

Comment: I think so, based on my admittedly flawed memory of reading this https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0, which might teach you more than you wanted to know. The basics I remember include that each function gets its own execution context which includes a couple of internal lexical environments (one of which is specific to those identifiers declared with `var`) and these lexical environments can access the outer environment. Also, I think `var` and `function` declarations get hoisted but `let` and `const` declarations don't...

Comment: The explanation is pretty simple. JS lets your functions reference variables that don't exist. So the potential for error only comes after the function is invoked. At the time of invocation, if the referenced variable doesn't exist, you get an error. As a test, remove the `add()` function, and update `multiply()` so that it uses a `try/catch`, where the `try` tries to call `add()`, and the `catch` creates it at `window.add = function() {...}`. You'll see that the *ReferenceError* is caught on the first invocation, but subsequent invocations succeed.

Comment: ...like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cpzj309w/

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the declarations are hoisted to the top, while the assignments are not.

However, functions don't keep the values of any variables outside of them from when they are created. Instead, they use whatever is in them when they are called. In this case, `add` is `undefined` when the `multiply` function is created, but is assigned a function before `multiply` is called, so `multiply` uses the new assigned function.

To see this more clearly, consider this code:

```js
var multiply = function(num) {
    return add(num) * 2;
};

// Would be an error
// console.log(multiply(1));

var add = function(num) {
    return num + 1;
};

console.log(multiply(1)); // Prints 4

add = function(num) {
    return num + 2;
};

console.log(multiply(1)); // Prints 6
```

The last `console.log` prints `6` because multiply used the new function in `add` instead of keeping the one it had before.